# SELECT WHERE ORDER

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

Is there any difference betweeen these 2 SELECT clauses

```
(1)SELECT * from DB where key1="XXX" and key2="yyy"

and 

(2)SELECT * from DB where  key2="yyy" and key1="XXX"
```

I have a index created for both keys and key1 is the primary key

Also , can I force the MySQL engine to use index2 ( for key2 ) instead of index1 ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query optimization - order of expressions in WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146586/query-optimization-order-of-expressions-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 0):

No, any decent database's query optimiser will make sure to execute the where clause in the order it sees best fit. It will also try to simplify or in other ways rewrite your boolean expression if it might result in a better execution plan.

In general, the SQL you're writing does not specify a specific way of executing things, it's left to the database to decide. The way this generally works is the query is parsed, simplified through certain rules and then it's logical representation is converted into multiple physical execution plans. Those plans are associated with an estimate of how costly they are based on heuristic and statistics on the tables. Then the plan with the least cost is chosen.